# {"Could not find installable ISAM."}

Tags: .net

As i m new to .Net programming,i have doubt and please clarify me.

I want create&Connect Database by using MS Access2007.

I Wrote Code as:

```
OleDbConnection con;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;DataSource=D:/Customerdetails.accdb");
   con.Open();
```

1.How to rectify this error {"Could not find installable ISAM."}
2.How to Know MS Access Driver name in my PC

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\odbc\odbcinst.ini Theres a list of drivers and the names there - you should be able to pick it out of that, programattically (eg look for preferential words) I notice by default win7 seems to come with way less drivers than it used to even with office installed.